# Registering view resource in dropwizard

Tags: dropwizard

I am complete newbie in Dropwizard and what I'm trying to do is follow tutorial (http://dropwizard.codahale.com/manual/views/#manual-views) to implement simple freemarker- based view. I did exactly what it says, but when I launch my app and navigate my browser to `http://localhost:8080/user`
jetty returns me 404.

```
package com.example.views;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/user")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public class UserResource
{

    @GET
    public UserView getUser()
    {
        return new UserView();
    }
}


package com.example.views;

import com.yammer.dropwizard.views.View;

public class UserView extends View {

    public UserView() {
        super("user.ftl");
    }

}

package com.example.service;

import com.yammer.dropwizard.ConfiguredBundle;
import com.yammer.dropwizard.Service;
import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Bootstrap;
import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Environment;
import com.yammer.dropwizard.views.ViewBundle;

public class WebCoreApplication extends Service<WebCoreConfiguration> {
    private final ConfiguredBundle[] bundles;

    public WebCoreApplication(ConfiguredBundle...bundles) {
        this.bundles = bundles;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<WebCoreConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        for(ConfiguredBundle bundle : bundles) {
            bootstrap.addBundle(bundle);
        }
        bootstrap.addBundle(new ViewBundle());
    }

    @Override
    public void run(WebCoreConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
            }
}
```

My user.ftl is in src/main/resources/com/example/views folder.

What am i doing wrong and how should i register jersey resource to react to requests?

Comment: You may want to take a look at some [open source Dropwizard projects](https://github.com/gary-rowe?tab=repositories) that I've put together. They'll provide answers to many of your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A sample Dropwizard service**

For a standard v0.6.2 Dropwizard application using Freemarker views, the following code could be considered boilerplate:

```
public class OpenIDDemoService extends Service<OpenIDDemoConfiguration> {

  /**
   * Main entry point to the application
   *
   * @param args CLI arguments
   * @throws Exception
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new OpenIDDemoService().run(args);
  }

  private OpenIDDemoService() {

  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(Bootstrap<OpenIDDemoConfiguration> openIDDemoConfigurationBootstrap) {

    // Bundles
    openIDDemoConfigurationBootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/images", "/images"));
    openIDDemoConfigurationBootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/jquery", "/jquery"));
    openIDDemoConfigurationBootstrap.addBundle(new ViewBundle());
  }

  @Override
  public void run(OpenIDDemoConfiguration openIDDemoConfiguration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    // Configure authenticator
    OpenIDAuthenticator authenticator = new OpenIDAuthenticator();

    // Configure environment
    environment.scanPackagesForResourcesAndProviders(PublicHomeResource.class);

    // Health checks
    environment.addHealthCheck(new uk.co.froot.demo.openid.health.OpenIdDemoHealthCheck());

    // Providers
    environment.addProvider(new ViewMessageBodyWriter());
    environment.addProvider(new OpenIDRestrictedToProvider<User>(authenticator, "OpenID"));

    // Session handler
    environment.setSessionHandler(new SessionHandler());  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you must add "application" in the url

```
http://localhost:8080/application/test
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding

```
environment.addResource(new UserResource());
```

to my `run()` method.